# Perl XS: create and return array of strings (char*) taken from calling a C function or undef on failure

Tags: perl, memory-leaks, xs

I have Perl XS code which calls a function from an external C library which returns `char **` (array of strings).

The XS code will eventually return back to Perl an array ref with all the string results in there. Or `undef` on failure.

I have 2 problems:

1. On program exit I get a core dump with messages about memory corruption, double free etc. (e.g. `double free or corruption (fasttop)`).
2. How to return an undef value from XS sub denoting that something went wrong (not an empty array)?

Additionally, if anyone can confirm that I am handling correctly the cases where strings from Perl into the C function are utf8-encoded (e.g. the input filename) or the results back from the C function (which may contain utf8 strings) are sent back to Perl OK.

Here's my code (which is modelled after https://stackoverflow.com/a/46719397/385390 If I got that correctly, example #1):

```
AV *
decode(infilename_SV)
    SV *infilename_SV
  PREINIT:
    char *infilename;
    STRLEN infilename_len;
    char **results;
    size_t results_sz;
    char *aresult;
    size_t I;
    SV **aresultPP;
    char *dummy;
    STRLEN dummy_len;
  CODE:
    infilename = SvPVbyte(infilename_SV, infilename_len)
    // call C function
    results = myfunc(infilename, &results_sz);
    if( results == NULL ){
      printf("error!");
      // HOW TO return undef (and not an empty array?)
    }
    // create a Perl array to be returned
    RETVAL = (AV*)sv_2mortal((SV*)newAV());
    for(I=0;I<results_sz;I++){
      results_sz = strlen(results[I]);
      // create a new Perl string and copy this result
      aresult = newSVpv(results[I], 0);
      av_push(RETVAL, aresult);
      // free results as returned by C call
      free(results[I]);
    }
    // free results as returned by C call
    free(results);
    // debug print results
    for(I=0;I<results_sz;I++){
      aresultPP = av_fetch((AV *)RETVAL, I, 0);
      dummy = SvPVbyte(*apayloadPP, dummy_len);
      printf("result: %s\n", dummy);
    }
  OUTPUT:
     RETVAL
```

Comment: results_sz - I am assuming based on usage your myfunc populates it with the size of the results.  You then seem to modify it inside the loop where you are it as a max for the loop.  I assume you meant to use it to pass to newSVpv as the size of the string but instead you pass 0 as the length essentially trying to store a string in memory that is too small to hold it.  You also seem to be freeing each of the items in results for some reason - I would likely wait to free it in the free(results) that you have after the loop.  I may be way off but there appears to be a number of issues there

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Just for the record ```newSVpv()```'s 2nd arg can be left zero in which case Perl will calculate the strling length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On program exit I get a core dump with messages about memory corruption, double free etc. (e.g. double free or corruption (fasttop)).

This was probably because you overwrote the loop variable `results_sz` inside the `for` causing undefined behavior.

> How to return an undef value from XS sub denoting that something went wrong (not an empty array)?

You can return `&PL_sv_undef` to signal an undefined value, see [perlxs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs) for more information. For example like this:

```
SV *
decode(infilename_SV)
    SV *infilename_SV
  PREINIT:
    char *infilename;
    STRLEN infilename_len;
    char **results;
    size_t results_sz;
    char *aresult;
    size_t I;
  CODE:
    infilename = SvPVbyte(infilename_SV, infilename_len);
    results = myfunc(infilename, &results_sz);
    if( results == NULL ){
      RETVAL = &PL_sv_undef;
    }
    else {
       AV *av = newAV();
       for(I=0; I < results_sz; I++){
          aresult = newSVpv(results[I], 0);
          av_push(av, aresult);
          free(results[I]);
       }
       free(results);
       RETVAL = sv_2mortal(newRV_noinc((SV*)av));
    }
  OUTPUT:
     RETVAL
```

> if anyone can confirm that I am handling correctly the cases where strings from Perl into the C function are utf8-encoded (e.g. the input filename)

To pass a Perl UTF-8 string to the C-function as an UTF-8 encoded character string you can use `SvPVutf8()` instead of `SvPVbyte()`, see [perlguts](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts#How-do-I-pass-a-Perl-string-to-a-C-library%3F) for more information. Example:

```
infilename = SvPVutf8(infilename_SV, infilename_len);
```

> or the results back from the C function (which may contain utf8 strings) are sent back to Perl

You can use `newSVpvn_flags()` instead of `newSVpvn()` to convert an UTF-8 encoded C-string to a Perl string. For example:

```
aresult = newSVpvn_flags(results[I], strlen(results[I]), SVf_UTF8);
```

Comment: `newSVpvn_flags(results[I], strlen(results[I]), SVf_UTF8)` can also be written as `newSVpvn_utf8(results[I], strlen(results[I]), 1)`

Comment: The core dumps are gone now, thanks for pointing it out - silly me! I have solved returning undef by using ```XSRETURN_UNDEF;```. With ```RETVAL = (AV *)(&PL_sv_undef);``` it returned a scalar-ref with undef contents.

Comment: @ikegami thanks, I am now using what you suggested. So now all works OK. In my Perl code I have string constants in utf8. So I ```use utf8;```. But if some user of my code omits that then problems arise. So I added some extra code: 1) XS: for input: ```infilename = SvUTF8(infilename_SV) ? SvPVutf8(infilename_SV, infilename_len) : SvPVbyte(infilename_SV, infilename_len);``` and for output ```newSVpvn_utf8(results[I], strlen(results[I]), 1)```. And back in Perl I do: ```my @newres = map { utf8::is_utf8($_) ? Encode::encode_utf8($_) : $_ } @results;``` if ```use utf8``` was omitted by someone.

Comment: @bliako, No, don't do that. That's completely wrong. It will give the wrong result on occasion! This is literally what we call "The Unicode Bug". Don't introduce a bug in your code to attempt to fix a bug in the user's code.